# Is MatchMedia.js included in Modernizr JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, modernizr

I'm currently using

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/master/matchMedia.js"></script>

<!--    <script>

</script>-->

    <script>
        if (matchMedia('only screen and (min-width : 1025px) and (max-width : 2048px)').matches) {
  // smartphone/iphone... maybe run some small-screen related dom scripting?



    $( document ).ready( function() {
                var $body = $('body'); //Cache this for performance

                var setBodyScale = function() {
                    var scaleFactor = 0.5,
                        scaleSource = $body.width(),
                        maxScale = 150,
                        minScale = 10;

                    var fontSize = scaleSource * scaleFactor; //Multiply the width of the body by the scaling factor:

                    if (fontSize > maxScale) fontSize = maxScale;
                    if (fontSize < minScale) fontSize = minScale; //Enforce the minimum and maximums

                    $('body').css('font-size', fontSize + '%');
                }

                $(window).resize(function(){
                    setBodyScale();
                });

                //Fire it when the page first loads:
                setBodyScale();
            });
            }
            </script>
```

Now if I replace matchmedia.js to Modernizr.JS then will my above code work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modernizr uses something similar called mq. Here's the documentation: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#mq.

Basically, you'd change your line to:

```
if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width : 1025px) and (max-width : 2048px)')) {
```

Comment: So after replacing modernizr. I only need to replace `matchMedia` to `mq`

Comment: Do we also need to remove `.matches`?

Comment: I'm using `if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width : 1025px) and (max-width : 2047px)').matches) {` but it's not working

Comment: You should make sure your build of Modernizr includes this functionality first. I've used this before without issues. Perhaps you should get it working with a very simple query (perhaps one from the documentation) first, then move onto your real code.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I'm just coming across this. @Jitendra: he also said  to remove .matches! http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq and http://craftedpixelz.co.uk/blog/conditional-js-with-modernizr-mq/